# Select links in div an set "animations"

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

Im trying to change the color of the links in a div (mouseover/mouseout), but it doesnt work... why?

html code:

```
        <div id="Navigation">

            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <a href="#">Projects</a>
             <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
              <a href="#">Forum</a>
               <a href="#">Contact</a>

        </div>
```

js code:

```
$('#Navigation a').mouseover(function() {

   $(this).css("color", "#75c3ff");
});

$('#Navigation a').mouseout(function() {

   $(this).css("color", "#c5c5c5");
});
```

Comment: I tested your code and it works.  Make sure the document has fully loaded before executing this code by placing it inside of the `jQuery(document).ready()` function.

Comment: use pure css. No need for javascript or jQuery. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: hmm after I had restarted my computer it worked... strange. As Cort3z said, Im using pure css code for that "animation" for now.
Thanks to all of you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use JS for what you can achieve with CSS.

```css
#Navigation a { color: #c5c5c5 }
#Navigation a:hover { color: #75c3ff }
```

Just a note - your code [is working](http://jsfiddle.net/T2DuR/)